# textacy installation Killed for no reason

Tags: python, docker, textacy

I am trying to install **textacy** on a **python 3.6 Docker image**. For no reason, the process crashes with a "Killed" statement in the end

Here is the command:

> pip install textacy

Here is the log:

```
Collecting textacy
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/3b/9c5ff72f826ca1a52b151dd58567888c9bebe0a8355ae8619b4d1400c6f2/textacy-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155kB) 
[...]
Collecting six>=1.11.0 (from jsonschema<3.1.0,>=2.6.0->spacy>=2.0.12->textacy)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyemd, python-levenshtein, networkx, cytoolz, toolz, pyrsistent
Building wheel for pyemd (setup.py): started
Building wheel for pyemd (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e4/ba/b0/1f4178a35c916b22fc51dc56f278125d4b8cfb0592e5f0cc24
[...]
Successfully built pyemd python-levenshtein networkx cytoolz toolz pyrsistent
Installing collected packages: numpy, pyemd, scipy, joblib, pyphen, urllib3, chardet, idna, certifi, requests, srsly, scikit-learn, python-levenshtein, tqdm, cachetools, decorator, networkx, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, blis, six, pyrsistent, attrs, jsonschema, wasabi, plac, thinc, spacy, toolz, cytoolz, textacy
Killed
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out: `Killed` wasn't due to textacy but to my Docker limitation. Docker requires at least 2Go of RAM in order to get textacy properly working.

I had only 512 Mo of RAM and therefore it crashed. Increasing the RAM to 2 Go solved my problem !